# Why am i getting this error in crystal reports "There must be a group that matches this field"

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having trouble identifying why i am getting this error when the group name is exactly the same as in the report field list (see photo). What am I missing?

crystal formula window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your report is no longer grouped on the 2nd argument within the Sum expressions.

Comment: MilletSoftware, I am not sure what you mean? Why is my report no longer grouped?

Comment: It is probably still grouped but someone changed the field/formula it is grouped on.